# Run multiple bash commands simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, bash

I want to create a python script that can start multiple instances of a bash script.

I have tried

```
import subprocess

    commands = '''
    bashcmd1
    bashcmd2
    bashcmd3
    '''

    process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate(commands)
    print out
```

But it stops at bashcmd2 and continues only if i hit CTRL+C .

Comment: That wouldn't even work in bash. Open up a shell and paste commands in that. It won't run them in parallel. You'd either have to affix an `&` after each command or have three separate bash instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're just running one bash with 3 commands in it.

If the commands aren't setting variables or depending from each other (else you would not be able to parallelize them), maybe you could create 3 `subprocess.Popen` instances instead:

```
commands = '''
bashcmd1
bashcmd2
bashcmd3
'''

for process in [subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', line], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
                for line in commands.split("\n") if line]:  # filter out blank lines
    out, err = process.communicate() # or just rc = process.wait()
    # print out & err
```

that command first create a list comprehension of `Popen` objects (list not generator so the processes start immediately), then perform a `communicate` to wait for completion (but other processes are running in the meanwhile)

The upside is that you can apply this technique to any script containing commands, and you don't need to use the shell `&` capability (more portable, including Windows provided you're using `["cmd","/c"` prefix instead of `bash`)

Comment: You're missing a `:`

Comment: correct. It's because I only edited my answer 425 times :)